# How to read a file on another server using ASP

Tags: file, asp-classic, shared

I need to read a file on another server/ domain that I own; the file is open to all (if I enter the path in a browser it downloads the file)

```
filespec =  http://cascoly-images.com/pix/symbiostock_image_info.csv
```

when I try to read it using ASP it returns 'permission denied' -- how do I find the actual path of that file?  (t other sites, so I can't just run the app on that domain)  here will be similar public

i'd like to do something like:

```
set fileobject = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

if  fileobject.fileexists(filespec) then
Set Instr1 = FileObject.OpenTextFile (filespec, fForReading, false, FALSE)
...
```

Comment: You need to send an HTTP request.

Comment: Filesystemobject is only for local files. If you want to get a file trough http use the "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" object. Even when the file is not XML.

Comment: thanks -- main problem was not knowing what to look for!